# C Program SQL Errol: Database is Locked

Tags: c, sqlite

Trying to Create a table into database by using the code.
While running the above code the output is Opened Database successfully but the error is SQL Error:: database is locked.

IDE: Code Block.

OS: Ubuntu.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int  rc;
   char *sql;

   /* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }

   /* Create SQL statement */
   sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
         "ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
         "NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
         "ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
         "SALARY         REAL );";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
   fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Table created successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And no other program is using the database when you run your program? No program crashed before while modifying the database?

Comment: I wrote another program to create database connection before. Don't know whether it is running or not.@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I closed the Program and close database now Table has created successfully. Thank You @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )